# blank screen in project with PHP Xampp in Linux Mint

Tags: php, xampp, fuzzy, ahp

[pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldmve.png)

hello, does anyone know why the web project i took from github is having a blank screen like this. in fact I followed every instruction listed in the readme file.

I'm doing my final studies and my research concentration is in Fuzzy AHP, if anyone knows a solution or even a demo program that can be given. despite all that, every answer given, I feel very grateful. thanks.

Comment: probably its some if statement that has been set to show nothing if some value is true or the page just doesnt have content you will have to show code cuz we cant do sh*t with images bro we need to see the code so that we can see whats happening in the backend of things

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I can't submit all the source code, and I don't know where the error code is that I should include in this comment. however, I still remember where I got the source code. and this is the link I can give https://github.com/efzyx/AHPFuzzy/tree/master

thnks.

Comment: no no lol edit your Q then add the code in your q just type EDIT at the top of the newly added code